# In Google appsScript, getSite(domain, name) does not run

Tags: google-apps-script, sites

```
var sitio=SitesApp.getSite('gl.miteco.es', 'miteco.biodiversidad');
```

// no funciona estas llamadas getSite ni ninguna parecida!

Comment: Can you specify the error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

for **no** G Suite hosted domain use **SitesApp.getSiteByUrl**

example

var site = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl ("https://sites.google.com/site/dckeepws");